# Google Cloud Pubsub message iterator.Next() times out instead of returning iterator.Done (Go client)

Tags: go, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to pull messages from a `Pubsub` subscription on an App Engine app. (The `GAE` app currently uses Go client library for `GCP`.) And after consuming all the queued messages, I am constantly hitting the following `RPC` error.

> rpc error: code = 13 desc = transport is closing

According to the doc, I'm supposed to get iterator. Done as an error from the `Next()` call after the last message in the queue, but it always returns the above RPC error.

Is it an intended behavior?

Comment: Hmm, now, on GAE, the MessageIterator.Next() call won't respond at all even though there are queued message for the topic.